# jQuery's closest find confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 3 of the same widgets on my screen, widgets as in 3 div tags with content which the user chooses to have on his/her screen, which s/he can move and arrange on the screen.  A bit like what iGoogle did.  So basically, they can have 0 or more of the same widgets on the screen.

I got this working by using classes in the html instead of ids.

```
<div class="widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer_1"></div>
<div>
```

So if I have 2 of these widgets, the users screen will have 2 widgets with the class `widget_1`, i.e. the above html will be in the html source twice.

Anyway, I have a button in the sub_header of the widgets which adds data to the `content` section of the widget, i.e.

```
$('.my_button').live('click',function() {
    get_data( $(this) );
});
```

That works fine, as in, if I click on the button in the first `widget_1`, only it's content will change, if I click on the button in the second `widget_1`, only it's content will change and it will not effect the other `widget_1`'s.

To do that I am using:

```
$(this).closest('.widget_1').find('.widget_content_1').empty().append( some_data_here );
```

My question is, I want to prepend a loading image into the content when a button is clicked in the `sub_header` of a widget, so I tried:

```
$(this).closest('.widget_1').find('.widget_content_1').prepend( "<img class='imgLoading' src='/img/loading_white_32.gif'></img>" );
```

This works in that it only displays a loading image in the widget in which the button was clicked, but it displays 2 images in the clicked `widget_1` if I have 2 `widget_1`'s on the screen, and it will display 5 images in the clicked `widget_1` if I have 5 `widget_1`'s on the screen.

Why is that happening?

It should be displaying just 1 loading image in the clicked `widget_1` no matter how many `widget_1`'s are on the screen.

Comment: I'm at a loss to explain this. Your code should work as expected. Can you reproduce the problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I've create a fiddle, but it's working as expecting... http://jsfiddle.net/rSN5w/2/

Comment: It might be that you're binding the `click` handler once per widget, which is unnecessary because `live()` installs a delegated handler that will receive `click` events from all the widgets. In other words, you have to make sure your `$('.my_button').live(..)` line only runs once.

Comment: So I guess my code is going this: http://jsfiddle.net/rSN5w/4/ based on the number of widgets added to the screen!

Comment: That seems to be it, yes. You will have to externalize that code so it occurs only once on the page, then.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know what the problem is!  Please add this as an answer and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code:

```
$('.my_button').live('click',function() {
    get_data( $(this) );
});
```

Runs once for each widget you create. This is unnecessary, and actually counter-productive, because a single call to `live()` installs a delegated handler that will "see" the `click` events bubbling from all the elements that match `.my_button`, whichever widget they reside in.

You have to find a way for that code to only run once (possibly in your widget's common initialization routine if it has one).

In passing, note that [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in favor of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since jQuery 1.7. The code above would become:

```
$(document).on("click", ".my_button", function() {
    get_data( $(this) );
});
```